# custom routing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a rails application that has a model named graphic and as any rails application there is normal routing like this

```
something.com/graphics/1
something.com/graphics/2
something.com/graphics/3
```

which will take you to the appropriate show pages. That I understand this is done in my routes by this statement

resources :graphics

Now come to find out the client wants to have the url to be like this

```
something.com/1
something.com/2
something.com/3
```

so if there is a number directly after the root url then like it to the graphic show action....any ideas on how to do this without messing up any other models

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for:

```
match "/:id" => "graphics#show"
```

You can refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for any further modifications.

Comment: Make sure you put that route at the bottom of `routes.rb`, or you'll mess up your other routes...